# C++ using g++, no result, no print

Tags: c++, g++

I'm slowly moving from using Python to using C++ and I don't understand how to run any code. I'm using the g++ compiler, but I get no results from my functions.

```
// arrays example
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int foo [] = {16, 2, 77, 40, 12071};
int n, result=0;

int main ()
{
  for ( n=0 ; n<5 ; ++n )
  {
    result += foo[n];
  }
  cout << result;
  return 0;
}
```

If I run this example inside VSCode and specify that I want to use g++ compiler it comes back with: `Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.`. If I compile it through cmd and run the task, a new cmd window flashes and nothing is happening.

I found the g++ doc which says how to compile with g++ and it shows the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main (){
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

But I can't even run the compiler because it says

```
error: '::main' must return 'int'
 void main(){
           ^
```

How can I print something in cmd or the ide terminal? I don't understand.

Comment: Your first example has an output. Check [here](https://godbolt.org/z/LBuSYn)

Comment: Maybe a small missunderstanding. The compiler does not _run_ your program. It only compiles it, then you have to run the compiled program.

Comment: in C++ there is no `void main()`

Comment: @churill thats correct, when I run the first example I expect to see some output in cmd. In my case it just opens and closes

Comment: @NutCracker thank you for the answer, but I have no idea what I'm looking at on that website.

Comment: @SPersonDPerson you have a source code on the left side and the output on the right side. In the middle there is generated assembly code. It is just a proof your code runs ok

Comment: I kept using the Visual Studio terminal and got flashing '!' in the margins.  Tried again using the GitBash terminal with tortoise and it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are using VSCode in a wrong way. You must know that it does not have integrated compiler by default but you need to compile source file in command line and run the executable:

```sh
$ g++ hello.cpp
$ ./a.out
```

Your first example runs with no problem. Check [here](https://godbolt.org/z/LBuSYn)

Your second example has an error because there is no `void main()` in C++. Instead, you need to have

```cpp
int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

If running the executable results in opening and closing the window you can fix that by using one of the following:

- shortcut

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   system("pause");

   return 0;
}
```

- preferred

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   do {
     cout << '\n' << "Press the Enter key to continue.";
   } while (cin.get() != '\n');

   return 0;
}
```

**Why std::endl is not needed?**

Some of the comments are suggesting that changing

```cpp
cout << result;
```

to

```cpp
cout << result << endl;
```

will fix the issue but, in this case, when the above line is the last line in the main function it really does not matter since program's exit flushes all the buffers currently in use (in this case `std::cout`).

Comment: I compile the program in cmd using g++ filename.cpp and I get an executable, but the executable does not return anything, it opens cmd and closes in less than a second.

Comment: @SPersonDPerson What is the content of your `filename.cpp`?

Comment: @SPersonDPerson "the executable does not return anything, it opens cmd and closes in less than a second" - It most likely *did* return something, but the CMD window just closed too fast for you to see it.

Comment: @SPersonDPerson you can try adding `system("pause");` before `return 0;` in your main function. Btw, this is a bad practice but can work for you now

Comment: If you change `cout << result;` to `cout << result << endl;`? This `endl` forces to flush the buffer, without it you program just exits probably before having time to really write.

Comment: I think the standard specifies that when `main()` exits, all open streams, including stdout, are closed and flushed

Comment: @NutCracker Thanks, system("pause") worked indeed. You said this is a bad practice. What is the best practice for printing things on the terminal or cmd?

Comment: @SPersonDPerson `system("pause");` is not really about printing things to terminal or cmd. You are printing the result just fine. `system("pause");` is more about pausing the window so you can take a look at the output, so it does not close in a second. Bad thing about `system("pause");` is that it is platform specific I believe but, if you are just learning, you can use it. Just keep in mind that it's not the best thing and that there are better ways (`preferred` section in my answer)

Comment: @NutCracker Again, thank you very much for the answers, really appreciate it!

Comment: @SPersonDPerson if it helped you please upvote it and accept it (green tick beneath the votes). Thank you