# Command system("pause") not found on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, fedora, vcpkg

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    cout << "HW\n";
    getline(cin,line);
    cout << "Your line is - " << line << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I want to do gui to factorio headless server by myself so i need to exec few bash scripts. I think i need function system() to that ?

I think I got problem with lib path. Please don't blame to wrong installed vcpkg. Paths is :

```
/opt/factorio/bin/x64/vcpkg/installed
/usr/include/c++/9/x86_64-redhat-linux
/usr/include/linux
/usr/include/c++/9/tr1
```

Command `system()` not found says Visual Studio.

Comment: Please, take a look at my answer and, if it helped you, please accept it (green tick beneath the votes) and upvote. If it didn't help you, write a comment.

Comment: `system("pause");` is a Windows-specific *hack*. My recommendation is that whoever taught you to use that should have a stern talking to.

Answer (score -1):

`system("pause");` is meant to be used only on Windows. It runs the Windows command-line "pause" program and waits for that to terminate before it continues execution of your program. That's why it's a bad practice to use it in your code, no matter if you are running your code on Windows or Linux.

Here is a better way you can achieve the same result:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   do {
     cout << '\n' << "Press the Enter key to continue.";
   } while (cin.get() != '\n');

   return 0;
}
```

instead of:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   system("pause");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes but, also i want to exec bash scripts. I tried use system to test for exec bash. So if it is doesnt exist on linux what is the way to launch .sh or make "cat" "ls" "cd" "echo" ?

Comment: If you have a bash script you want to execute, then this would help `./script.sh`. But I didn't really understand what you are asking here?

Comment: sry. I have bad english. Execute bash script inside of c++ program. Because i want to have gui.

Comment: I think you are messing things up. Don't try to execute bash scripts inside your C++ program because that won't you give the GUI as you think so. On Linux, your GUI is the terminal.

Comment: Actualy no. I didnt downvote your answer. I just waited for better answer or something. I still searching for ways to exec bash script , i thought it is simple. Now i get that command system is useful in WIndows. You replaced "pause" but not way put the command to the terminal. I tried to upvote your answer, because it's actually smart replace for my code line.

Comment: @ЯрославМаревский Well, your question doesn't say anything about executing the bash script. You may ask another question regarding that. And you may want to check this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59918809/c-using-g-no-result-no-print/59918898#59918898) and my answer. It may help you